# "Can not" vs. "cannot"

Tags: meaning, differences, negation, modal-verbs, spacing

Is there a difference in meaning and/or connotation between "can not" and "cannot"?

I have read and seen both used interchangeably, but I know people who argue for a slight difference in meaning. That is, *cannot* indicates that there is an incapability whereas *can not* indicates the possibility of absence. Is this a real difference?

Comment: The linked question does not directly address this matter, but the accepted answer does.

Comment: Yes, there's a real difference.  There's some brief discussion in Zwicky and Pullum's 1983 [*Cliticization vs. Inflection*](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/mrg.readings/ZPCliticsInfl.pdf) (page 9 of the PDF), which in turn cites Horn's 1972 dissertation *On the semantic properties of logical operators in English*.

Comment: @snailboat: They are clearly talking about the two different _phonetic_ realisations, though (as indicated by the fact that they employ stress marks), which do not necessarily correspond neatly to the two different orthographic forms.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you read the cited Horn (not available online), you'll see that he asserts there is an orthographic convention distinguishing the two (where *can not* is ambiguous, but *cannot* is not).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are acceptable, but *cannot is* now more common. OED has this much to say about *cannot*:

> (ˈkænət)
>   the ordinary modern way of writing *can not*: see CAN *v.*

Notwithstanding, in some situations ambiguity may arise if you write *can not*, and the difference might not be a minor one. Compare:

- *I cannot make love to you.* (*Something is stopping me from it, be it objective or subjective.* Put differently: *I **am not able to** make love to you*.)
- *I can not make love to you.* (Same as above. But also: *Reckon with the possibility of my refusing to make love to you.* Put differently: *I **am able to** not make love to you.*)

Comment: Btw, I will not often say (ˈkænət,ˈkænɒt); it's almost always (kəˈnɑt) or more emphatically (kæˈnɒt). OED doesn't make a mention of that typically American pronunciation, but some other dictionaries do.

Comment: This is a great answer. If I could offer a little clarification. What Talia is saying is that someones the expression isn't joined in one word because "not" doesn't belong to the "can."  In the second sentence the not is attached to "make" rather than "can." it is "I can not-make love" rather than "I can-not make love"

Comment: @FraserOrr I believe Talia Ford is saying that the second sentence has both interpretations available.