# Cannot vs. Can Not

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between "cannot" and "can not?"

Don't they mean the same? It's kind of crazy if they don't.

We learned all about it in 6th grade, but you know how that goes: in one ear and out the other.

Comment: Yes, there can be a difference, especially w.r.t. scope of negation and emphasis.

Comment: If you believe that the answers given by the linked-to question do not answer your question, please edit your posting to explain what you are still trying to understand which is not answered by any of those other answers there. That way your question can be re-opened here and you can get an answer that you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

OED-cannot definition:
the ordinary modern way of writing *can not*

Both **cannot** and can not are acceptable spellings.

There’s no difference in meaning between cannot and can not.
 but the *cannot* is much more usual.

Some references from ELU - [can't vs cannot](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78935/when-to-use-cannot-versus-cant)

[Why is “cannot” spelled as one word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132600/can-not-vs-cannot)..(a few exceptions)

Comment: This doesn't seem right. "The variable cannot be initialized" --> *it's a pretty useless variable*. But, "The variable can not be initialized" --> *it is possible for the variable to be in a non-initialized state*. So, "cannot" means something (denoted S) is *impossible*, while "can not" means the inverse of that something (denoted !S) is *possible*. These two statements do not imply each other. Of course, the second statement could be rendered much more clearly as "The variable can be not initialized," by moving the "not" next to the word being negated.

Answer (score 3):

They do mean the same thing, but common usage over time has made one form more "usual" than the other (namely `cannot`).  It's similar to contractions (`can't`, `don't`, `won't`), except it seems acceptable to use `cannot` in a formal setting whereas contractions are frowned upon.

Source: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/cannot-or-can-not/

Comment: If cannot = can not, whynot donot = do not, or willnot = will not, funknot = fun knot, etc, etc, whatnot.

Comment: You're asking a question about consistency in English, which, sadly, no one has an answer to.  Contractions seem to have superseded the need for `donot` and `willnot`.  I predict that other common usages like "noone" might make it into circulation in the future, though (much like someone and whoever).